# Count elements in list via a recursive method

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to get a grasp on recursion. In general I understand what it does, but I'm having some trouble understanding how the following method works.

```
def count_numbers_in_list(list):
  if list == []:
    return 0
  return 1 + count_numbers_in_list(list[1:])
```

Now I get that `list[1:]` returns everything from the given list except the first.

But what I can't get my head around is that we are never calling something like - 1 on the list itself. So this function works perfectly, but it would also make sense to me that this function returns a infinite loop.

I'm hoping that somebody could explain precisely to me what's happening here.

Thanks!

Comment: You should determine what `list[1:]` does.

Comment: `I get that list[1:] returns everything from the given list except the first.` You have the answer.

Comment: Still, if you have problems, debug using `print` statement. You should get it easily enough.

Comment: Would it help to put `print(list)` in just after the `def` statement? Then  exercise the function by calling it with a short list. And incidentally *never* use a key word such as *list* as a variable name. Doing this will eventually bite you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses! means alot ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I get that **list[1:]** returns everything from the given list except the first.

Actually you've already found out the answer explaining why that function works perfectly.

```
return 1 + count_numbers_in_list(list[1:])
```

Every time recursion is performed, `count_numbers_in_list` is given a shorter list until there is no element left in it:

Let's break this down. Consider you have the below list:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`count_numbers_in_list` is given `[1, 2, 3, 4]` at first:

1. `0 + count_numbers_in_list([1, 2, 3, 4])`
2. `(0 + (1 + count_numbers_in_list([2, 3, 4]))`
3. `(1 + (1 + count_numbers_in_list([3, 4]))`
4. `(2 + (1 + count_numbers_in_list([4]))`
5. `(3 + (1 + count_numbers_in_list([])))`
6. `(4 + (count_numbers_in_list([])))`
7. `(4 + 0)`

Result is `4`.

Comment: Right! I've used the `print` method as well to show me exactly what's happening in the function. But when it finally comes to an empty `[]` we say: `if list == []: return 0`. How does this function still returns 4 (in your case) even after we call `return 0` on line 3?

Comment: If you look at each step, you'll see the returned value is incremented every time recursion is performed as you add `1` to the value coming from previous recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This recursive counting method is basically saying "if my list is empty, that's my base case. There are 0 elements here. Otherwise, I can count just one of the elements, and then I can count the rest of the list."

So "1+" is saying "count one of the elements". "count_numbers_in_list(list[1:])" is saying "count everything except the first element in the list."

Then you just think of it as deferred execution of some sort, or a stack if you're familiar with that. Say I have the list [1, 2, 3]. The recursive statement says "return 1 plus whatever you calculate as the result of count([2, 3])". Similarly, the answer to [2,3] is 1 plus whatever the answer to [3] is. 3 is 1 + the answer to [], and our base case says the answer to [] is 0. So [3] resolves as 1 + 0 = 1, and passes it back up to [2, 3]. That resolves as 1 + 1 = 2, and 2 gets passed back up to the result for [1, 2, 3]. That resolves as 1 + 2 = 3, and that's your final answer.